# Why is "user" time different for same executable on two different AMD machines?

Tags: c++, time, architecture, c++17, sys

Have tried execute the below source code on two different AMD machines which has same configurations.

The "user" times are different for both the machines

Same Source code is compiled with gcc 9 on both machines.
They have the same objdump on both the machines.

Here is the **source code** :

```
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int a = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
        {
            if(i%1000000 == 0)
                a = i;
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("The elapsed time is %f seconds\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on **Machine 1:** (Details on Machine type mentioned below)
The elapsed time is 21.140000 seconds
real    **21.14**
user    21.14
sys    0.00
mem:    520

Output on **Machine 2:** (Details on Machine type mentioned below)
The elapsed time is 24.580000 seconds
real    **24.59**
user    24.58
sys    0.00
mem:    524

**Machine 1 Details:**
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                128
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-127
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    32
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            23
Model:                 49
Model name:            AMD EPYC 7542 32-Core Processor
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2894.795
BogoMIPS:              5789.59
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-31,64-95
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     32-63,96-127

**Machine 2 Details:**
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                128
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-127
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    32
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            23
Model:                 49
Model name:            AMD EPYC 7542 32-Core Processor
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2894.705
BogoMIPS:              5789.41
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-31,64-95
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     32-63,96-127

Already tried below options:
(1)used "tasket" to pin the application to a particular CPU
(2)used "nice" & "renice" to change the priority of process
(3)tried executing same source code from /tmp directory to ensure there was no network lag issues.
(4)there is no load on the machines.
(5)Have also tried using -o2, -o3 optimizations.
(6)tried executing with sudo, still i notice consistent time difference in the execution on source code on two different machines which have same configurations.

Could someone let me know as to why same source code being executed on two different AMD machines having same configurations is providing different "user" time

Comment: There is in fact a difference: _CPU MHz: 2894.795_ vs. _CPU MHz: 2894.705_ I'm not sure whether this small difference can be responsible to measure 3 seconds difference over roundabout 20 seconds. However, the two computers might be not that identical as you assume. Different workload due to installed demons? Different temperature of CPUs while performing the tests? There's still room for a lot of guessing...

Comment: How do you compile? If you enable optimisations, does it result in real 0.00 user 0.00 sys 0.00 mem 520?

Comment: Yes if compiled with optimizations time (sys/user) does reach 0.00.
In order to prevent that added a "printf"   inside for loop so that optimization does not ignore the loop

Comment: hows the ram structured? do they both have the same ram speed, same ram structure (same types same slots)?  Could be a difference in the OS, maybe other apps are eating CPU time?  Due to scheduling there is no guarantee any given run of an application will get the same time on the CPU.